# How to install Python2.7.5 in Ubuntu docker image?

Tags: python, docker, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have specific requirement to install **Python 2.7.5** in Ubuntu, I could install 2.7.18 without any issues

Below is my dockerfile

```
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=18.04
FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_VERSION

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y python2.7.x \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

however if I set it to **python2.7.5**

```
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=18.04
FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_VERSION

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y python2.7.5 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

it is throwing the following error

> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.7.5'

I want to install Python 2.7.5 along with relevant PIP, what should I do?

Comment: When you say "it is throwing the following error", what actually produces the PNG file you show?  Can you configure that tool to use colors with better contrast, or better still, delete the image and replace it with a textual error message?  Can you reduce the Dockerfile to a [mcve]; is the part about installing mssql relevant to the Python installation question, for example?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This version is no longer available in canonical mirrors.

It has been released in 2013.

As a result, having both `python` and `pip`  working together since then is challenging.

### Python 2.7.5 + PIP on centos7

It may be the simplest way if `ubuntu` is not a requirement.

```
ARG CENTOS_VERSION=7
FROM centos:$CENTOS_VERSION

# Python 2.7.5 is installed with centos7 image
# Add repository for PIP
RUN yum install -y epel-release

# Install pip
RUN yum install -y python-pip

RUN python --version

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

### Python 2.7.5 on ubuntu

I've been able to install it from source

It has not been a success to install `pip` :

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py

```
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=18.04
FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_VERSION

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.5

# Install dependencies
# PIP - openssl version > 1.1 may be an issue (try older ubuntu images)
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget gcc make openssl libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
  && apt-get clean

WORKDIR /tmp/

# Build Python from source
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && tar --extract -f Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && cd ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION/ \
  && ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local \
  && make && make install \
  && cd ../ \
  && rm -r ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION*

RUN python --version

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

### Python 2.7.6 + pip on ubuntu

Ubuntu 14.04 still has mirrors working (how long ???).

Python packages are really close to your expectations.

You may try to run your scripts with that one.

```
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=14.04
FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_VERSION

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python python-pip \
  && apt-get clean

RUN python --version

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

### Python 2.7.5 + pip, not working but could on ubuntu

Here is what I've tried with no success.

```
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=16.04
FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_VERSION


# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget gcc make openssl libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
  && apt-get clean

WORKDIR /tmp/

# Build python from source
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && tar --extract -f Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && cd ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION/ \
  && ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local \
  && make && make install \
  && cd ../ \
  && rm -r ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION*

# Build pip from source
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py \
    && python get-pip.py

RUN python --version

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

### Python 2.7.9 with pip - as requested in comment

You can use this dockerfile, building python includes pip.

```
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=16.04
FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_VERSION

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.9

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget gcc make openssl libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
  && apt-get clean

WORKDIR /tmp/

# Build Python from source
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && tar --extract -f Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz \
  && cd ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION/ \
  && ./configure --with-ensurepip=install --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local \
  && make && make install \
  && cd ../ \
  && rm -r ./Python-$PYTHON_VERSION*

RUN python --version \
  && pip --version

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

Comment: Python 2.7.5 on ubuntu - It works. However I could not install PIP with that, any suggestions?

Comment: can you help me with Python 2.7. 9 as it has PIP by default? https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/#is-pip-installed-with-python

Comment: @MugilKarthikeyan, Yes I hope, please see my updated answer.

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: pip: not found

Comment: I've just tried this dockerfile. is this message shown when you do `docker run` ? in that case, `python` is image entrypoint which means, you can not do this `docker run <image> /bin/sh pip` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults

Comment: it works fine with UBUNTU_VERSION=16.04 but not on UBUNTU_VERSION=18.04?

Comment: docker build is failing with UBUNTU_VERSION=18.04 with the error "/bin/sh: 1: pip: not found " after printing the python version.

Comment: @MugilKarthikeyan, yes...,  I'm suspecting libssl-dev version which is too new for python 2.7.9. As a result pip is not collected and installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237608/discussion-between-mugil-karthikeyan-and-etienne-dijon).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tgz
tar xzvf Python-2.7.5.tgz
cd Python-2.7.5
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After installation completed set installed python as default one.